# Metal basement window frame casement rotted out

Tags: basement

[image]

We bought a house that was completely remodeled but the metal framing for the basement window was left even though they installed a new window. The rust is beyond repair. Does anyone have experience wrapping the frame with aluminum? What can be done ? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. This is such an eyesore .

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm no expert, but I'm guessing that steel against aluminum in a wet environment would be corrosion city.

Comment: Is the steel an old window frame or a wrap on a wooden buck?

Comment: You’re right Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd get some thin (1/4" or 3/8") vinyl plank and some white soffit nails and cover it as-is. Fill the outer section out flush with the inner stop using treated lumber and wrap it all. Caulk the joints blind as you assemble the parts.

Here's a plan view section of the right side:

```
___________________ ___
   vinyl window    |   |
___________________|   |
                *|_    |< -- old steel window frame
                *|x|   |
                *|x|   |
                *|_|___|*
                *********
                  ^--------- filler block (x)
                ^ ---------- vinyl plank wrap (*)
```

Comment: Isherwood -thank you .  And if I had to guess this was the original frame. There was a fire and house sold at sheriffs auction and someone fixed it and flipped it . We bought the house but there are a lot of question marks with this home. Wish we never bought it seeing a lot of problems

Comment: You're welcome. No home is trouble-free. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works and what's expected of you. Good luck with your projects.